# How to .map around things inside another .map

Tags: javascript

I have a main array of options and inside it there are array of values, I am using vanilla js and want to map around the first array (`options`) and then inside that map, I want to map around another array(`values`). But this is not working, what can be the solution for this?

```js
test.innerHTML = match_id.options.map((modalVari, indexVariposition) => {
     return   `
    <fieldset class="modal-variant-form">
        <legend class="modal-variant-title">${modalVari.name}:</legend>`
        + modalVari.values.map(varival => (`<li>${varival}</li>`)).join("")
    `</fieldset>
    `
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Any Errors ? you can create working demo app

Comment: It didn't show anything

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: First of all you're adding an `li` without a proper parent like `ul` or `ol`. You're also joining the inner `map` but not the outer one, resulting in an array of strings.

Comment: @Reyno, I try joining on the outer one also and adding h1 instead of li, still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

this works as expected, so the problem is another

```js
const data = [{name: 'one', values: [1, 2, 3]}, {name: 'two', values: [4, 5, 6]}]

const test = document.getElementById('test')

test.innerHTML = data.map((modalVari, indexVariposition) => {
     return   `
    <fieldset class="modal-variant-form">
        <legend class="modal-variant-title">${modalVari.name}:</legend>
        <ul>${modalVari.values.map(varival => (`<li>${varival}</li>`)).join("")}</ul>
    </fieldset>
    `
    }).join('');
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```